# C# DataGridViewComboBoxCell Selecting Item changes Value Type

Tags: c#, datagridview, datarow, datagridviewcomboboxcell

I've got a problem with the DataGridViewComboBoxCell behavior.

I've several *TextBoxColumns* and one *DataGridViewComboBoxColumn*.
I add rows programmatically and add Datarows as items for the ComboBoxCell. I set the *DisplayMember* of the cell to a property of the row ("String").

Things work fine so far. The value of the property is shown and when I access the *Value* Property of the cell I get the Datarow. When selecting another item from the cell, the value of the cell is changed to the content of the "String" property instead changing it to the underlying DataRow. The *Items* collection of the ComboBoxCell stays the same, and when I build up the DGV again I again get the underlying DataRows as values.

Can anyone explain to me why the DatagridviewComboboxcell behaves that way? When accessing the value I always want to get the Datarow, not the FormatedValue of the DisplayMember.